# How often are OSM data in Cesium updated with new OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, update, cesium

When users make edits to OpenStreetMap(OSM), or OSM data gets updated by any other means, how long does it generally take for those edits to show up in Cesium Ion or Cesium Sandcastle? Is this on the order of hours, days, or months? And what about other sources like Mapbox, ESRI data?

Comment: the data in OSM is immediately added to the OSM database. However, it can differ a lot of how long it will take until the new features update on the map. The map on https://www.openstreetmap.org is much up to date. For other datasources it depends on your provider (e.g. Mapbox ... )

Comment: My concern is that does the updated OSM map appear on Cesium when I add OSM baselayer on the Cesium Globe?